# CSS: How do I make autosuggest results align with input field

Tags: css, alignment, autosuggest

I can't seem to make the results of my autosuggest field align with my input field if I move my input field to somewhere else on the page. I was wondering if I would use position: absolute or what? Heres the code for my index page:

```
<input type="text" class="autosuggest"> <input type="submit" value="Search">

<div class="dropdown">
   <ul class="result"></ul>
</div>
```

And heres my CSS code:

```
body{
 font:0.8em Verdana;
   }

.autosuggest, .dropdown, .result {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  width:250px;
}

.autosuggest {
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.result {
  width:260px;
  list-style:none;
}

.result li {
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-top:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result li:hover {
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is? This looks fine to me. How are you moving your input field to somewhere else?

Comment: then remove the question from stackoverflow or post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your `input` and `.dropdown` by relative positioned wrapper, and add `position:absolute` for `.dropdwon`. Than try to position `.dropdown` by changing top and left.

Somthing like that http://jsfiddle.net/zsUuK/6/